# Optical Bloch oscillation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, photons

I have a doubt about how the optical Bloch oscillations happen in a 1D photonic crystal. I try to explain: in a photonic crystal with discrete translational symmetry in one direction I superimpose a second bigger periodicity by means of microcavities. These reduce the amplitude of the first Brillouin zone. Now it is found that minibands are formed, that correspond to delocalized states. If now I introduce a gradient in the refractive index in the longitudinal direction, the minibands are tilted and a Wannier-Stark ladder of states is created. How can I explain the oscillation of an optical pulse from the Wannier-Stark states in the real space? (I ask this because in many articles the Bloch oscillations in real time are explained as the Fourier transform of the Wannier-Stark ladder but I'm not able to appreciate this point of view).

Comment: I don't know about optical Bloch oscillation, but Bloch oscillation in general can be understand in these two pictures: the Bloch oscillation and Wannier-Stark pictures. These two pictures corresponding two independent choices of gauges, the velocity gauge and the length gauge. In the Bloch oscillation picture, the eigenfunctions of the system are the Houston states (accelerated Bloch states). In the Wannier-Stark picture, the eigenfunctions are the Wannier-Stark states, and the Bloch oscillation can be understand as the quantum beating of a superposition of two eigenstates of the system.